# trim the string when starts *Artist*

Tags: java, string, api

CurrentlyPlaying(context=null, timestamp=1610137729201, progress_ms=38105, is_playing=false, item=Track(name=Put Your Head on My Shoulder, artists=[ArtistSimplified(name=Paul Anka, externalUrls=ExternalUrl)

i want to turn it into *Paul Anka* and another ones what will be in this row
so this what i tried:

````
            String info = currentlyPlayingFuture.get().toString(); // returns first text
            System.out.println("just: " + info);
            char[] infoCh = info.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < infoCh.length - 1; i++) {
                if ((infoCh[i] + infoCh[i + 1]+"").equals("Ar")){
                    System.out.println(info.substring(i, i+10));
                }
             }
            ```
and it doesn't works. how to do it?
````

Comment: Have you tried RegExp?

Answer (score 0):

> and it doesn't works. how to do it?

The problem is `infoCh[i] + infoCh[i + 1]+""`.  That isn't concatenating characters.  It is concatenating the ascii values of those characters.  One thing you could do is turn that into `"" + infoCh[i] + infoCh[i + 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

A regex would work better than what you are trying here. Something like

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ArtistSimplified\\(name=(.*?), ext");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The best solution would perhaps be to parse the string into some object structure though.

Comment: Just carefull as this will not read fully eg "Sean Paul, Sandra Gomez"